# How can I make an link to an action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

At the time I have two models: Patient (has many), and Treatment (belongs to).

Until now I displayed the form for a new treatment on the patient show page and all worked fine. But now i want to outsource the treatments form to an new page. To visualize it better:

```
 <%= render "treatments/form" %>
```

change to:

```
 <% link_to "new", "treatments/form" %>
```

SO my problem is that I always become an route error:

```
 No route matches [GET] "/patients/treatments/form"
```

But the routes look so, and i thought they would work:

```
resources :patients do
  resources :treatments
  resources :paintings
end
```

And the controller of the treatments:

```
class TreatmentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @treatment = @patient.treatments.create(params[:treatment])
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
end

def destroy
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @treatment = @patient.treatments.find(params[:id])
    @treatment.destroy
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient)  
end
end
```

Comment: read here [creating-nested-resources](https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080)

Comment: there have been many questions about creating a link_to a controller action. Please search for answers to your question before posting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your proposed `form` is really just a way of creating a new patient treatment, you should consider following RESTful conventions and create a new `TreatmentsController` action called `new`:

```
# app/controllers/treatments_controller.rb
class TreatmentsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
end
```

Since your treatments routes are a nested resource of the patients nested resource routes, you'll need to pass the `patient_id` to your link helper:

```
<%= link_to "New Patient Treatment", new_patient_treatment_path(@patient) %>
```

This will enable you to properly access your nested route for `treatment#new`.

Comment: Ok, strange now i get the error: No route matches [GET] "/patients/patient/:id/treatments/form"

Comment: What does your `link_to` look like?

Comment: Ok sorry now it should work! I get the errror Missing template treatments/new, application/new with ! But i think i know how to solve it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Indeed, a `treatments/new` template should resolve your issue. Since this answer put you on the right path, would you consider accepting it as correct?

Comment: Oh sorry! I was so busy to view your website, i have to say i liked it very much! i missed the like button! @zeantosi But one more little thing, how can i change my treatments/new controller so that it does not redirect to patient/treatments after every save procees? It would be nice if it stays on the create site and that the user has an new blank form! I hope you understand me?

Comment: If you want to do that, you should redirect to the same `new` action. In your `create` action, replace `redirect_to patient_path(@patient)` with `redirect_to new_patient_treatment_path(@patient)`.